# how to disable a button when a textbox becomes readonly?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a button and text box inside a stackpanel, when text box gets readonly state then the button should disable, i want to do this in XAML only is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding is easy to define but you need a converter to invert the boolean value. Since you want to enable (`IsEnabled = true`) the Button when the TextBox is not readonly (`IsReadOnly = false`).

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
       <local:InvertBooleanConverter x:Name="invertBoolConverter"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox x:Name=textBox />
    <Button IsEnabled={Binding IsReadOnly, ElementName=textBox, Converter={StaticResource invertBoolConverter}}/>
</StackPanel>
```

`local` is a namespace you define in your UserControl that points to the namespace of the InvertBooleanConverter

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NamespaceOfTheInvertBooleanConverter"
```

**Converter**

```
public class InvertBooleanConverter: IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    bool currentValue = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);

    return !currentValue;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
    bool currentValue = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);

    return !currentValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="targetTB">Hello</TextBox>
            <Button  Content="Test Button">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=targetTB, Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>

                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=targetTB, Path=IsReadOnly}" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

try this, it can work as you need.